# Socket Programming on BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am stuck creating a socket connection between blackberry client and java server. I need simple sample code which extends the socket API example from blackberry sample code.

We have a server that communicates with android systems and we need it to work with blackberry client as well.

Comment: I referred the balckberry help but I was unable to understand and implement it using this example:  http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/7693/Use_a_socket_connection_508960_11.jsp

Comment: Am not able to understand the bellow code? What does the getHostFieldText do and etc: String url = "socket://" + _screen.getHostFieldText() + ":6667" + (_screen.isDirectTCP() ? ";deviceside=true" : "");                                    
            connection = (StreamConnection)Connector.open(url);

Comment: Value of _screen.getHostFieldText() will be an ip address or server address, replace it with your desired server address. 6667 is the port number of the server (replace it with the port number your server). And to open a socket connection over direct TCP, append the deviceside=true parameter to the end of the URL. But if you use BlackBerry MDS Services then append deviceside=false.

Comment: @Rupak: What about _screen.isDirectTCP? Can you please write the example URL. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for being late. And I am posting my comment here because of comment length. _screen.isDirectTCP() isn't an API method, so I am not sure what does this method return. But from the method name/signature I think this method is only used for checking whether Direct TCP connectivity is available or not on the device. Depending on the result, the application will append the connection parameter such as ";deviceside=....".

From the [Network Transport](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Network-Transports/ta-p/482457) article,

> If you do not want your application to rely on the  default connection
>   types described in the  previous sections, explicitly state the
>   desired connection type by adding the “deviceside=”  parameter to the
>   destination URL. If an application appends “;deviceside=true” to the 
>   destination URL, then only a direct HTTP or TCP connection is
>   attempted. The application does  not attempt to connect to the network
>   using the BlackBerry MDS. Alternatively, if an application  appends
>   “;deviceside=false” to the destination URL, then the application only
>   attempts  to connect to the network using the BlackBerry MDS. The
>   application does not attempt to  connect to the network using a public
>   IP gateway.

Also please have a look at this link, [What Is - Different ways to make an HTTP or socket connection](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/796557/800451/800563/What_Is_-_Different_ways_to_make_an_HTTP_or_socket_connection.html?nodeid=826935&vernum=0).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It helped us to create a socket. However when I create the socket between Android and BlackBerry it is disturbing the already created socket between Android Client and Server. Any Help in this regards will be appreciated.